# SQL subquery + multiple inner joins efficiency and errors

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm fresh with SQL and have had a hard time adapting examples online to solving this problem.

I have three tables with contact information. I need to match the contacts based on similar identifiers.

The goal is to determine which contacts match on business name, telephone number, and first name between a hubspot crm export and a list of doctors sorted by their National Provider Identifier (NPI). Once I find the matches between these two tables, I need to match the contact NPIs to another table full of medicare contacts that also have NPIs.

This breaks my db but gives you the breakdown of what I need:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM npidata AS n, hubspot_crm_export_contacts AS h, medicare AS m
WHERE n.Provider_Organization_Name_Legal_Business_Name = h.AssociatedCompany
AND n.Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Telephone_Number = h.PhoneNumber
AND n.Provider_First_Name = h.FirstName
AND n.NPI = m.NPI
```

This is what I've determined I should be going for but I get the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'h.PhoneNumber' in 'on clause'. Note that I've yet to match NPI data between the npidata and medicare tables in this code which I still need:

```
SELECT *
FROM hubspot_crm_export_contacts AS h
WHERE h.AssociatedCompany IN (
SELECT n1.Provider_Organization_Name_Legal_Business_Name
FROM npidata AS n1
INNER JOIN npidata AS n2 ON h.PhoneNumber =  n2.Provider_Business_Mailing_Address_Telephone_Number
INNER JOIN npidata AS n3 ON h.FirstName = n3.Provider_First_Name)
```

Comment: You cannot use the h.PhoneNumber into the subquery in the IN.

Comment: You are using `select *` with `GROUP BY`.  That is just broken SQL and makes it totally unclear what you are trying to do.